# Very slow JVM threads creating (very long pauses in java.lang.Thread.setPriority0())

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, jvm

We have a JVM performance issue on one of our host machines.

The host machine is 16 CPU cores, 16Gb RAM, Windows Server 2012 is the host OS. JVM is 1.8 131, Xmx is 10Gb, but 2-3Gb is enough for the normal operation and the consumption is rarely rises higher.
The app uses all cores but the CPU usage is very low - maximum 15%. GC activity is low.

The same app with the same configuration operating on other hosts has no performance issues and easily eats more 2-3Gb RAM and CPU as it needs.

But on this particular host the app became near unresponsive when some load begins. We have predefined core sizes of several thread pools and when the app starts to increase that pools by creating new threads - it almost stuck.

Thread dumps look very strange. A lot of running threads with java.lang.Thread.setPriority0() executed for a long time period.

Like:

```
"Thread-14592" #676532 daemon prio=3 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000026852000 nid=0x15a0 runnable [0x000000003737e000]    
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE    
at java.lang.Thread.setPriority0(Native Method)    
at java.lang.Thread.setPriority(Unknown Source)    
at java.lang.Thread.init(Unknown Source)    
at java.lang.Thread.init(Unknown Source)    
at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Unknown Source)    
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DefaultThreadFactory.newThread(Unknown Source)    
at com.util.NamedThreadFactory.newThread(NamedThreadFactory.java:38)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init>(Unknown Source)    
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(Unknown Source)    
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)    
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
...
```

The `setPriority0()` can run for a couple of minutes, so the app performance is terrible on this host.

We've tried to set -XX:-UseThreadPriorities but with the same results.

Can someone give us a clue what we should look at to find the reason for the described behaviour?

Comment: It is worth noting that you can't raise priority unless you are running as Administrator and changing the priority only matters if you don't have free cpus. If you have free cpus, a thread can run regardless of priority.

Comment: Any anti-virus or disk encryption?

Comment: That's strange, overall CPU usage is very low. Anti-virus is present on all hosts, it has the same configuration and provide no problems on other hosts.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Note that `setPriority` gets called from the `Thread` constructor, rather than from the OP's code. I guess, it's the very first thing accessing the native thread and there's the problem. Some funny Windows-antivirus-whatever bug....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an antivirus indeed.

Don't know what particular settings of it, but when the antivirus was turned off the app returns to a ordinary fast'n'furious flow.